Unable to login into outlook email server with smtplib even after setting app passkey and 2 factor auth
I am unable to login into outlook email server with smtplib even after setting app passkey and 2 factor authentication in outlook account.
import smtplib

smtp_server = 'smtp.office365.com'
smtp_port = 587
sender_email = 'myemail@outlook.com'
app_password = "my_outlook_app_passwords"

def login_stmplib():
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(sender_email, app_password)
        print("Login successful!")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Login error: {e}")

    finally:
        server.quit()

login_stmplib()

It fails with an error given below. main5.py contains above code with outlook credentials.
(EmailEnv) ayushraj@pclocal emailer % python main5.py

Login error: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [PN2PR01CA0158.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-10-18T09:14:28.211Z 08DCEEEF057DFEC7]')

I have been able to login successfully with gmail credentials. main6.py contains above code with gmail credentials.
(EmailEnv) ayushraj@pclocal emailer % python main6.py

Login successful!


My endgoal is to use this python pgm to send emails.
Ps: I've setup 2 factor authentication and then used App password from outlook. Adding ss for the same.


Basic authentication, including app passwords, is now completely disabled.

@DmitryStreblechenko then what’s the way to automate email sending from python script?

Also for gmail app passwords still works somehow.

Gmail does not belong to Microsoft, Google is a totally independent company, and they don't like Microsoft much :-)

Hey, @DmitryStreblechenko I'm aware they are diff companies. I'm asking what's they way how can I automate sending emails from outlook email via script.

Unless you support OAuth, you cannot unfortunately.
